# PHP nao publica dados em tabela MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ola!

Eu sou iniciante em PHP, estou tentando construir um formulário HTML que deve utilizar um código PHP para enviar os dados para uma tabela MySQL.

Acontece que o código PHP simplesmente não faz nada... não publica os dados e não retorna erro algum...

Alguém poderia me ajudar, indicando o que posso estar fazer errado? ficarei muito grato!

Segue abaixo o código PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$con=mysqli_connect("url","user","pass", "db_name");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

  $name = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['nome'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $rua = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['rua'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $numero = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['numero'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $bairro = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['bairro'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $cidade = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['cidade'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $telefone = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['telefone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $nascimento = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['nascimento'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $email = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $deficiencia = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['deficiencia'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $deficienciasim = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['deficienciasim'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $escolaridade = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['escolaridade'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $formado = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['formado'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $sexo = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['sexo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $estadocivil = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['estadocivil'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $filhos = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['filhos'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $habilitacao = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['habilitacao'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $possuiveiculo = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['possuiveiculo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $situacaoatual = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['situacaoatual'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $pretensaosalarial = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['pretensaosalarial'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $regime = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['regime'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $podeviajar = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['podeviajar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $conhecimentosespecificos = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['conhecimentosespecificos'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  $falesobrevoce = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['falesobrevoce'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

  $conhecimentos = mysql_real_escape_string($conhecimentosespecificos);
  $falesobre = mysql_real_escape_string($falesobrevoce);

  $areadepreferencia = array();
  $area=implode(', ', $_POST['areadepreferencia']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO moderacurriculovesp (nome, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, telefone, nascimento, email, deficiencia, deficienciasim, escolaridade, formado, sexo, estadocivil, filhos, habilitacao, possuiveiculo, situacaoatual, areadepreferencia, pretensaosalarial, regime, podeviajar, conhecimentosespecificos, falesobrevoce) VALUES ('$name', '$rua', '$numero', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$telefone', '$nascimento', '$email', '$deficiencia', '$deficienciasim', '$escolaridade', '$formado', '$sexo', '$estadocivil', '$filhos', '$habilitacao', '$possuiveiculo', '$situacaoatual', '$area', '$pretensaosalarial', '$regime', '$podeviajar', '$conhecimentos', '$falesobre')");

// ENVIA EMAIL
$to      = 'user@email.com';
$subject = 'Assunto do email';
$message = 'Corpo do email';
$headers = 'From: user@email.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: user@email.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//

header('Location: mensagem_enviada.html');

?>
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: vc instalou o apache? para começar uns teste comente a linha do `header(loca...)`

Comment: instalei sim... inclusive ja tenho outros bando de dados, uma pagina, outros códigos PHP neste mesmo servidor... tudo funcioando direitinho.

Comment: Habilite o php a mostrar os erros.

Comment: quando vc roda esse código a tela fica em branco? coloca isso no início do script `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo!

O problema era o seguinte, nas linhas:

```
$conhecimentos = mysql_real_escape_string($conhecimentosespecificos);
$falesobre = mysql_real_escape_string($falesobrevoce);
```

Eu usei "mysql" em vez de "mysql**i**"...

Habilitando os erros como indicado pelo @rray foi possível descobrir!

Muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram!